# Runtime error when calling a switch method

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript and tying this out but I get error

```
getluck(luckyNumber) {

  switch (luckyNumber) {
    case add:
      console.log(1 + 1)
      break;
    case subtract:
      console.log(2 - 1)
      break;
    case divide:
      console.log(2 / 3)
      break;
    case multiply:
      console.log(2 * 9)
      break;
    default:
      console.log('I lose')
      break;
  }
}
```

calling it as `getluck(subtract)`. Am i doing it wrong?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Have you declared the variables `add`, `subtract`, etc?

Comment: Try reading the error.

Comment: @Barmar I was running in jsbin. which says "SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at https://static.jsbin.com/js/prod/runner-4.1.2.min.js:1:13850
    at https://static.jsbin.com/js/prod/runner-4.1.2.min.js:1:10792"

Comment: You're missing the `function` keyword at the beginning of the function definition.

Comment: so much wrongness ... `function getluck(luckyNumber)` for a start ... then, if `add`, `multiply` etc are not declared variables, you'll end up with more issues

Comment: It sounds like you need to get a good Javascript tutorial or textbook and learn basic syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to send a variable which is not defined and case statements are also checking on variables which are not defined. Please make them to strings or define those variables.

```
function getluck(luckyNumber) {
            switch(luckyNumber) {
        case 'add':
            console.log(1+1)
            break;
        case 'subtract':
            console.log(2-1)
            break;
        case 'divide':
            console.log(2/3)
            break;
        case 'multiply':
            console.log(2*9)
            break;
        default :
            console.log('I loose')
     }
}

getluck('add');
```

Comment: Did you try this? open console and try

Comment: A good answer should explain what was wrong and how you fixed it, not just dump a bunch of code. But the other answer is identical and has those details, so this one doesn't really add much value.

Comment: Done! Edited with much details!

Comment: thnx for the help, why we need to use case as string, what I know about cases are with numberic value u don't pass it in quotes.

Comment: Yes if it is numeric value you can pass number values